# GCC m68k pc-relative

Tags: c

I was using a Microtek toolchain to generate an executable binary with relocatable code (pc-relative) and data from a fixed address (Absolute data). Today, this toolchain does not work on Windows 7 64 bits. The idea is to replace Microtek toolchain for 68000 with the GNU toolchain (GCC 4.8.0).

But I can not find the same options on the gcc compiler:

Microtec compiler "MCC68K" with:
"-Mcp": Directs the compiler to use PC-relative addressing for all code references.
"-Mda": Directs the compiler to use absolute addressing for all data references.

Gcc (m68k-elf-gcc) with:
-mpcrel

Unable to build with gcc relocatable code with no relocatable data as the Microteck compiler. With "-mpcrel", all is relocatable (code and data).

do you have an idea?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve the same result with the GNU m68k toolchain.

- `-mpcrel` will generate fully position-independent code with
  pc-relative adressing for code as well as for data, resulting in a
  limited program/data size (pc-relative offsets cannot exceed 16 bits).
- `-fpic` and `-fPIC` will generate position independent code with
  relocatable binaries but will require a special loader that does the in-place relocation

Answer (score 0):

From [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html)

> -fpic Generate position-independent code (PIC) suitable for use in a shared library,...
>
> -fPIC If supported for the target machine, emit position-independent code, suitable for dynamic linking and avoiding any limit on the size
>   of the global offset table.

Also try to [search](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2004-05/msg00102.html)